# TikZ intersection command with strange behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am trying to put some nodes at the intersection of a circle with some bissectors. However, the intersections are not behaving how I supposed they should.

The text *wrong* should be placed at the intersection of circle and gray line, but it is somehow at an apparently random place:

[image: Current situation]

Furthermore, if the commented lines are uncommented, both intersections are put at the exact same spot:

[image: Still wrong and strange]

(The blue text is exactly where it is supposed to be, though.)

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? I don't understand why the node is put at the wrong place in either case.

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[thick,dashed, name path=circ] (2,2) circle (2cm);
            
            \begin{scope}[shift={(2,2)}]
                \filldraw (165:2) node[left=3.5pt] (c) {\large $c$} circle (3pt);
                \filldraw (225:2) node[below=3.5pt] (b) {\large $b$} circle (3pt);
                %\filldraw (135:2) node[above=3.5pt] (a) {\large $a$} circle (3pt);
            \end{scope}  
            
            %\path[shorten >=-0.5cm,-, name path= path1] let \p1=($ (a) !.5! (b) $) in (2,2) -- ($(\p1)+(5,0)$);
            %\draw[name intersections = {of =circ and path1}] (intersection-1) node[blue] (ab) {\Large right};
            \path[shorten <= -0.5cm,-, name path=path3] let \p1=($ (b) !.5! (c) $) in (\p1) edge[gray] (2,2);
            \draw[name intersections={of=circ and path3}] (intersection-1) node (bc) {wrong};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make sure your example actually compiles! Here `\begin{document}` and the tikz `calc` library is missing

Comment: Note that `shorten <= -0.5cm` trick does not seem to apply to the actual length of that path only the displayed version, thus the actual named path never intersects the circle. (also this seems to be an easier method to draw it `\draw[shorten >=-0.5cm,name path=path3] (2,2) -- ($(b) !.5! (c) $);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of make sure your MWE actually compiles, here `\begin{document}` and the tikz lib `calc` are missing.

Secondly, the problem here is that in `\path[shorten <= -0.5cm,-, name path=path3]` the `shorten` part does not add to the length of the path (the part that can be used for calculations), it only adds to the displayed version. Thus the line segment used to calculate the intersection is completely inside the circle and you get an error about it not being found.

This seems to work

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,dashed, name path=circ] (2,2) circle (2cm);
  
  \begin{scope}[shift={(2,2)}]
    \filldraw (165:2) node[left=3.5pt] (c) {\large $c$} circle (3pt);
    \filldraw (225:2) node[below=3.5pt] (b) {\large $b$} circle (3pt);
    % \filldraw (135:2) node[above=3.5pt] (a) {\large $a$} circle (3pt);
  \end{scope}  
  
  % \path[shorten >=-0.5cm,-, name path= path1] let \p1=($ (a) !.5! (b) $) in (2,2) -- ($(\p1)+(5,0)$);
  % \draw[name intersections = {of =circ and path1}] (intersection-1) node[blue] (ab) {\Large right};
  % \path[shorten <= -0.5cm,-, name path=path3] let \p1=($
  % (b) !.5! (c) $) in (\p1) edge[gray] (2,2);
  
  \coordinate (d) at ($(b) !.5! (c) $);
  \coordinate (o) at (2,2);
  \draw[name path=path3] (o) -- ($(o)!1.5!(d)$);
  \draw[name intersections={of=circ and path3,by=e}] (e) node (bc) {wrong};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I switched to the standallone class as it is more suitable for this type of question. Also removed the `figure` env as it is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep in mind your general changes for future MWEs ;) A question: is there a reason to prefer using a new coordinate instead of using two points inside the `let .. in`? For example `\path[-, name path=path3] let \p1=($(b) !.5! (c) $), \p2=($(2,2)!1.5!(\p1)$) in (\p2) edge[gray] (2,2);` ?

Comment: @B.Dors not sure, I just think the syntax gets much too complicated. The simpler code is much easier to follow.